# How to convert Monte Carlo 3 speed fan and light remote to two wall switches

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

This Monte Carlo ceiling fan has 3 wires for motor speed control and is designed to use the remote. 
Wires are labeled - Motor one, motor 2 motor 3. I do not want to use the remote. I have two wall switches for fan and light. The fan switch will have adjustable speeds. How do I wire the 3 wires to the wall switch?

Comment: What do those 3 wires go into?  Did you acquire this fan new, or used/upcycled?

Comment: Do you have any model number information for the fan?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The three wires go to the ceiling fan transmitter. It's a new fan, made by Monte Carlo. model #14PRR62AGPD

Answer (score 1):

### Return the fan and get one that isn't married to an OEM remote

Sadly, you have a "DC" (read: electronically commutated/variable-frequency-driven) ceiling fan there.  As a result, the remote receiver for the fan contains a bunch of drive electronics (an itty bitty VFD, fundamentally) that are required to turn 60Hz wall mains into a set of signals the fan motor can use.  So, you'll need to return that fan and get a completely different fan if you want to use it with any speed control other than what the fan OEM provides.  (Unless you wish to try to hack it to run off a small industrial VFD, that is!)

Comment: Or mount the remote on the wall and voila, you have a wall switch.  Most fans with remotes include a wall mount bracket.  I find that adding an actual wall power switch to such fans creates confusion with multiple points of control.